# How to send WM_COPYDATA from C++ to AutoHotKey?

Tags: c++, winapi, autohotkey

Trying to **SendMessage** with `WM_COPYDATA` from a C++ application to an AutoHotkey script.
I tried to follow the example found in the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-data-copy

Then I did:

```
HWND htarget_window = FindWindow(NULL, L"MyGui");

std::string str = "Hello World";

COPYDATASTRUCT cds; 
cds.dwData = 1; 
cds.lpData = (PVOID) str.c_str();
cds.cbData = strlen((char*)cds.lpData); 
auto Response = SendMessage(htarget_window, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)htarget_window, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

And in the Autohotkey script:

```
OnMessage(0x4a   , "Receive_WM_COPYDATA")
    
Receive_WM_COPYDATA(wParam, lParam) {
           
   ; Retrieves the CopyDataStruct's lpData member.
   StringAddress := NumGet(lParam + 2*A_PtrSize)
   ; Copy the string out of the structure.
   Data := StrGet(StringAddress)    
   MsgBox Received the following string: %Data%
    
}
```

**The message is being received**, but this is the output:

[image]

When it should be: `Hello World`.

I have also checked for `GetLastError()` after the `SendMessage` and it output `0`.

I must be doing something wrong inside of the `COPYDATASTRUCT`.
AutoHotkey x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `StrGet()` is wrong:

- You are not including the `std::string`'s null terminator in the sent data, but you are not passing the value of the `COPYDATASTRUCT::cbData` field to `StrGet()`, so it is going to be looking for a null terminator that does not exist. So you need to specify the length that is in the `COPYDATASTRUCT::cbData` field, eg:

  ```
  StringLen := NumGet(lParam + A_PtrSize, "int");
  StringAddress := NumGet(lParam + 2*A_PtrSize);
  Data := StrGet(StringAddress, StringLen, Encoding);
  ```
- More importantly, you are not specifying an `Encoding` for `StrGet()`, so it is going to interpret the raw data in whatever the native encoding of the script is (see `A_IsUnicode`). Don't do that. Be explicit about the encoding used by the C++ code. If the `std::string` holds a UTF-8 string, specify `"UTF-8"`. If the `std::string` holds a string in the user's default ANSI locale, specify `"CP0"`. And so on. What you are seeing happen is commonly known as [Mojibake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), which happens when single-byte character data is mis-interpreted in the wrong encoding.

Comment: Using the latest version x64, the script crashes with your code: `AutoHotkey closed for the following exit code: 3221226525` and the message is still in Chinese characters, i also tried your suggestion to use `StringAddress := NumGet(lParam + A_PtrSize + 4)` it also crashes, in this case crash even before the MsgBox, when I send just one char it does read it correctly, like `std::string str = "X";` The 4º example in this link demonstrates the use of WM_COPYDATA between two AutoHotkey scripts https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm

Comment: @Gutth did you verify that `StringLen` is receiving the correct number of characters being sent? Did you verify that the received `dwData` field is 1? Maybe you are processing a different `WM_COPYDATA` message than you are expecting?

Comment: Got it working now with: `StringLen := NumGet(lParam + A_PtrSize, "int")
   StringAddress := NumGet(lParam + 2*A_PtrSize)
   Data := StrGet(StringAddress, StringLen, Encoding)`, could you edit it in your answer? also, thank you for the help Remy! :)